# How do I add control variables when doing SEM in Mplus?

Tags: structural-equation-model

I have ENG BY ENG1 ENG2 ENG3, PSY BY PSY1 PSY2, DIS BY DIS1 DIS2 DIS3 DIS4, EMP BY EMP1 EMP2 EMP3, and control variables are DEM1 DEM2 DEM3 DEM4 DEM5.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.